# How to serialize json with fields name as datamember only?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, utf8json

I have a POCO like this:

```
public class Process
{
    public Process() { }

    [DataMember(Name = "lang_code")]
    public string LCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "data_currency")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "country_code")]
    public string CCode { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

Now when I serialize my POCO I get json back like this which has field name:

```
{"LCode":"en-US","Currency":"USD","CCode":"IN"}
```

Is there any way to get it the way `DataMember` fields are after serializing POCO. Something like below:

```
{"lang_code":"en-US","data_currency":"USD","country_code":"IN"}
```

Below is the code we have:

```
ProcessStr = ExtractHeader(headers, PROCESS_HEADER);
Console.WriteLine(ProcessStr);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProcessStr))
{
    Process = DeserializeJson<Process>(ProcessStr);
    if (Process != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Process.Gold))
    {
        Process.Gold = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Process.Gold);
    }
    ProcessStr = Process.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(ProcessStr);
}

private T DeserializeJson<T>(string str) where T : new()
{
    try
    {
        return Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(str);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use `[JsonProperty("lang_code")]`, etc for Json.NET.

Comment: I tried it. Doesn't work as well. And I get null value for that field after serializing POCO to JSON.

Comment: Maybe `DataMember` works with `UTF8Json`. Since I am using that for deserializing in my `DeserializeJson` method.

Comment: I didn't spot that. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using two different packages, `Newtonsoft.Json` to serialize and `Utf8Json` to deserialize. They use different annotations. You *can* get it to work, but it might be simpler to choose one or the other.

`Newtonsoft.Json` uses the `JsonProperty` attribute whereas `Utf8Json` uses the `DataMember` one.

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Utf8Json;

namespace JSONPropertyTest
{
    public class Process
    {
        public Process() { }

        [JsonProperty("lang_code")]
        [DataMember(Name = "lang_code")]
        public string LCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data_currency")]
        [DataMember(Name = "data_currency")]
        public string Currency { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("country_code")]
        [DataMember(Name = "country_code")]
        public string CCode { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static private T DeserializeJson<T>(string str) where T : new()
        {
            try
            {
                return Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(str);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new T();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Process { LCode = "en-US",Currency = "USD", CCode = "IN" };
            var json = test.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine($"serialized={test}");
            var deserialized = DeserializeJson<Process>(json);
            Debug.Assert(test.CCode == deserialized.CCode);
            Debug.Assert(test.LCode == deserialized.LCode);
            Debug.Assert(test.Currency == deserialized.Currency);
            Console.WriteLine($"deserialized={deserialized}");
        }
    }
}
```

---

To just use `Utf8Json` you need to update your `ToString` method, which is the only one in the code you've shown that relies on `Newtonsoft.Json`. That would look like this:

```cs
    public class Process
    {
        public Process() { }

        [DataMember(Name = "lang_code")]
        public string LCode { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "data_currency")]
        public string Currency { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "country_code")]
        public string CCode { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.ToJsonString(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I need to do it via `Utf8Json` then how can we do it?

Comment: It's in the code above... It uses Utf8Json *and* Newtonsoft.JSON just like you are doing. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Oh hang on, now I understand what you mean. Will update!

Comment: yeah thats what I meant. Let me test it out.

Comment: One last question. Is there any way that `Utf8Json.JsonSerializer` can ignore null fields while serializing in `ToString` or that is considered bad practice to do?

Comment: I'm not sure on that one. Might be better to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Sure got it. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Opened a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64883796/exclude-null-fields-while-serialization-using-utf8json-library) and no response yet. I also read the doc and couldn't find there as well so looks like maybe it is not possible to do this using `Utf8Json` library unless I am wrong here.