# Exclude null fields while serialization using Utf8Json library?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, utf8json

Is there any way to ignore null fields while serializing POCO to JSON string using `Utf8Json` library?

I have a `ToString` method in my below class which I am using externally so I wanted to see if there is any way to exclude null fields while doing serialization? Basically I don't want null fields in my json string after serialization. I am using `Uft8Json` library here.

```
public class Process
{
    public Process() { }

    [DataMember(Name = "lang_code")]
    public string LCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "data_currency")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "country_code")]
    public string CCode { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.ToJsonString(this);
    }
}
```

I tried reading the docs but couldn't find it. Is there any way to do this using `Utf8Json` library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [resolver](https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json#resolver):

```
return Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.ToJsonString(this, 
    Utf8Json.Resolvers.StandardResolver.ExcludeNull);
```